# why does (Function('return this'))(); return global?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
(Function('return this'))();
```

I observed this technique in instanbul for nodejs. When executed in a window it has a similar effect. It will also work regardless of where this is executed. Ie, inside of another function etc.

Comment: This is a way to get hold of global object. No matter where you execute it, it will always return global object. This can be useful  when you don't know in what environment app is running (nodejs, browser).

Comment: @dfsq - what about in strict mode?

Comment: Seems to work in strict mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Function()` works like an indirect eval call, which always executes in the global scope.

http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html